# How to make this text bigger?

Tags: css, text

I've been fiddling around and trying to figure out how to make the text from within a WordPress menu list bigger and I just can't figure it out.

The URL is here

- http://www.playstoresales.com/top-charts/

And I just want the text in the main list(games, top free games, top adventure games, top action games, etc) to be bigger.

I can't seem to find out which CSS class(or whatever) that I should be targeting, and what the syntax for it is.

Comment: Have you tried using the browsers developer tools? `F12` and then use the element selector tool to mouse over the text. It should show you the exact CSS class names and styles that are used for any element on the page.

Comment: I have, and I've tried all sorts of different CSS tags to try and adjust it. You can see that I tried the example that another user gave below and it still didn't do anything. I think I'm just going to have to contact the developer of the WordPress theme or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the level of control but a nuclear option that would change the font size of every `li` element that has a CSS class of `.menu-item` would be:

```css
.menu-item {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

For a little more control you could target that specific menu with an additional CSS class. I see you already have class (`.menu-=top-charts-container`) and id (`#menu-top-charts`) to hook onto.

```css
/* all elements with .menu-item class */
.menu-item {
    font-size: 18px;
}
/* only elements with .menu-item within #menu-top-charts element */
#menu-top-charts .menu-item {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful with this. Nested menu-items will cause the font-size to grow huge using "em" as your font-size. Edit: I see you changed it.

Comment: See, it's so strange. I added that to my WordPress theme's custom CSS code box and it doesn't change anything. I even set it to 500px and still, nothing.

Comment: I was just able to get it working with third line of code that you had suggested. It was Amazon's Cloudfront CDN that was preventing me from seeing the changes. I feel so embarrassed. I had kept clearing the cache, but I guess that wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
.menu-item.parent > a { font-size: 30px; } /* Or whatever font you want */
```

That being said, you may want to try tagging all the links that you want to have bigger text with a css class, that way you can target the class instead of adding selectors.

Like this:

```
.main-link { font-size: 30px; } /* All hyperlinks you want to be bigger can have this class */
```

Comment: @doug Try the first css rule I wrote up above. If you can't add any css classes to your html, I believe the first thing I wrote above should give you the control you need.

Answer (score 1):

Targeting the anchor within the ul ID;

```
    #menu-top-charts a {
    font-size: 50px;
    }
```